# How to empty the <ul> in the nest <li> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a menu and its sub menu, but receiving the data from database. And I created the menu successfully, this is my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetMenuList";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var mainMenu = $("#content ul#navmenu-v");
        $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) { 
           var new_li = $("<li id='level1'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" 
                       + dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>" + 
                       dataOption.Name + "</a>");
        mainMenu.append(new_li);

    });
     $('.selectedcategory').mouseover(function () {
     $("ul#subCat").empty();
     $("li#level1").append("<ul id='subCat'>");
     var urlCat = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetCategoryList";
        $.getJSON(urlCat, { Depid: this.id }, function (dataCat) {
           $.each(dataCat, function (indexCat, dataOptionCat) {
           $("ul#subCat").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' 
              class='selectedsubcat' id='" + dataOptionCat.id + "'>" + 
                dataOptionCat.Name + "</a></li></ul></li>");
           });
       });
   }); 
  });
});
```

This is the HTML :

```
<div id="content">
 <ul id='navmenu-v'>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But it didn't get the right sub menu due to the main menu.
Could anyone show me some suggestion please.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Does the menu need to dynamically change, if not, can you not just fill the menu when the page loads server side?

Comment: it would help if you show your html for the menu too

Comment: @cpoDesign : I added in the above of my code.

Comment: @MatthewRiches : Yes, It is dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this looks like what you want I hv simulated it here http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetMenuList";
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    var mainMenu = $("#content ul#navmenu-v");
    $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {
       var new_li = $("<li class='level1'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='"+ dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>" + dataOption.Name + "</a>");
       mainMenu.append(new_li);

    });

    $('.level1').hover(function(){
       $(this).append("<ul class='subCat'></ul>");
       var ul=$(this).children('ul');

       var urlCat = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetCategoryList";
       $.getJSON(urlCat, { Depid: $(this).find('a.selectedcategory').attr('id')}, function (dataCat) {

         $.each(dataCat, function (indexCat, dataOptionCat) {
           $(ul).append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0);'" +
           "class='selectedsubcat' id='" + dataOptionCat.id + "'>" +
            dataOptionCat.Name + "</a></li>");
          });
        });
      },function(){
      $(this).children('ul').remove();
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried ur code, the problems are when I take the mouse over the main menu , the sub menu are shown, but I cannot mouse over on the sub menu, it is hide when I mouse over on it. The 2nd problem, when I move my mouse down to up, the data in the sub menu are combine with another sub menu.

Comment: Ok I have updated the code, sorry I overlokked that part try now, i have not taken into account your styling that might work differntly though. Demo fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/9/

Comment: Thanks Deepu, I tried the code, but it is only create `<ul class='subCat'><ul>` only, have no <li> in it.

Comment: verify if you have missed something or verify your json response, I have done the same in the jsFiddle code above and you can see it working there, did you try to debug in Firebug?

Comment: Yes sure Deepu, It is only  <ul> in the Firebug.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to replace the ul#subcat with ul object in selector, updated accordingly now above and here in fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/10/

Comment: Plz note that I have changed the ID you had for li level1 and ul subCat to classes to follow HTML standards and I suggest you follow the same. Hope this works for you

Comment: `this.id` is not defined in here Deepu.

Comment: Have changed it in the answer, I guess you could have figured it out since we are invoking the hover on the li element you can just find the anchor with selectedcategory class and get its id.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are closing your HTML in a wrong order, you are closing the Ul and its outer LI inside the each loop

Comment: Thanks Deepu, but the <li> at there, refer to the main menu above it.

Comment: yes but since ur using append it will close on the first iteration thus rendering a different lay out. did you try closing it after the each loop

Comment: or just remove the </ul> and </li> at the end and try the browser should auto close the tags at correct order

Comment: I removed it, but It still the same before.

Comment: do you have a fiddle source that i can take a look at?

Comment: K the issue here is that your adding the elements for all the upper level menu items on mouseover and you are not removing it on mouseout  http://jsfiddle.net/d4udts/W9cCE/3/